# Селекторы jQuery - Выборка элементов по индексу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет! Пытаюсь сделать выборку всех третьих элементов `<td>` в каждом `<tr>` и применить стили, но получается выбрать только один третий элемент `<td>` первого `<tr>` (всего их у меня 3):

```
$($('tr td')[2]).css('color', 'red');
```

Почему это работает именно так? Как сделать, чтобы выбрать то, что надо?

Comment: `$('tr td:nth-child(3)').css('color', 'red');`

Comment: `$("tr td:nth-child(3)").css("color", "red");`

Comment: Упс............

Comment: Вы же выбираете ВСЕ `td`, после чего из них берете 3тий .... а работает так потому что так работает ... учите css селекторы

Comment: Дошло, спасибо! )